How to "fix" user input on the django admin page datetime input
I have a model Itineraries that has a tabularInline model ItineraryDetails that has destination, arrival, and departure times. I want to allow users to input 09302025 and 700 for each datetime field but I can't seem to get it to work.
Django admin looks for valid datetime objects before saving and since these are not valid, they can't be saved. I've tried save_model and save_related, but they won't accept the invalid datetime format

I think I've found a solution using django's widgets. This might be a bit overkill but it seems to work.
class CustomDateTimeInput(DateTimeInput):
    input_type = 'datetime-local'
    format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'

    def __init__(self, attrs=None):
        final_attrs = {'placeholder': 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'}
        if attrs:
            final_attrs.update(attrs)
        super().__init__(attrs=final_attrs)


class ItineraryDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    departure_time = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=CustomDateTimeInput,
        input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'],
        required=False
    )
    arrival_time = forms.DateTimeField(
        widget=CustomDateTimeInput,
        input_formats=['%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'],
        required=False
    )

    class Meta:
        model = ItineraryDetails
        fields = ['destination', 'arrival_time', 'departure_time', 'type']

    def clean_departure_time(self):
        departure_time = self.cleaned_data['departure_time']
        if departure_time:
            departure_time = departure_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        return departure_time

    def clean_arrival_time(self):
        arrival_time = self.cleaned_data['arrival_time']
        if arrival_time:
            arrival_time = arrival_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
        return arrival_time


class ItineraryDetailsInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = ItineraryDetails
    form = ItineraryDetailsForm
    extra = 0

